# checking a folder structure and moving empty ones

Tags: c++, windows, directory

okay, following Problem. We have a quite large folder structur with several sub folders and want to check if one of the sub folders is empty, if so, the program should move the folder into a different folder.

I try to explain it this way

```
go into main folder
search in subfolders for an empty folder
if there is an empty folder move the complete folder into a different directory
```

so there is a main folder with maybe 100 subfolders and every of these has another 3 folders. and if a special one "done" is empty the whole folder with the 3 subfolders should get moved into "not yet done"

I'm quite a newbie, so please be gentle ;)

Comment: Post whatever code you have so far and what the OS is.

Comment: The [Boost filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) library could be used for this.

Comment: sadly there is no code yet, I don't have any real idea how to get it done, we tried Batch but the task was, I think, a bit to complex to realise it with batch.
the OS is windows XP Pro

Comment: You can always use some other scripting language then batch. For example  [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/). By default it has tons of stuff to handle files and directories. Writing a script such as this should be easy peasy ;)

Comment: OT: I think, being a SO member for over a year now, doesn't qualify as newbie anymore ;-)